# How to Split datagrid Rows Extjs

Tags: datagrid, extjs

I want to split my dataGrid Rows , like we do in Html by using ...

this picture illustrate what i'm asking for

[view the screenShot](http://h-elam.clanteam.com/shot.png)

I tried with the gridView and Xtemplate , i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **do not want** each row of the split rows to work as individual rows of a GRID, then you can simply use renderer() function to show simple HTML template in your PHONE and EMAIL column. Have a look at this [paging grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/paging.html) example - the way the used String.format to show custom template.